# how to embed one to many sonata admin child views

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I know you can add fields of a child view in sonata admin by point referencing child.field in the show view, but that only works for one to one relationships. I have a one parent - many - child relationship.
And this does not work:

```
<?php $showMapper->add('child', 'sonata_type_model',array(), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                ))
```

Although it works great for the formMapper. How are you supposed to do this? If it is through the twig view please give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

For the `ShowMapper` you just do `$showMapper->add('child');`

However it will most of the time only display a link to the child object.

As you suggested you can also directly render child fields with

```
$formMapper->add('child.field');
```

But it will not work for collections

To customize the rendering when having a collection you can make your own template extending `SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig`

In the template your child object(s) will be in the `value` variable wich you can loop on to display each element

Then add your field specifying the template

```
$showMapper->add('children', null, array('template' =>'MyBundle:CRUD:MyCustomTemplate.html.twig'));
```

Comment: thank you, I found that out too. I ended up with a twig template like this, since i also needed children's children data:
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    {% for val in value %}
        <b>{{ val.field1 }}</b><br>
        {{ val.field2 }} <br>
        {{ val.field3 }}
        {% for child in val.childrenschildren %}
            {{ child.datefrom|date('Y-m-d') }} - {{ child.dateto|date('Y-m-d') }} {{ child.name }}T/W
            </br>
        {% endfor %}
        <br><br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}